# Range("F1").column returns error "The remote server machine does not exist...."

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am processing an Excel spreadsheet in Access and converting an Excel column letter to a number using the code listed below.  The `ColRef` has a value of `"F"`.  Running the function with the exact same input and process sometimes results in a

> "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" error

and sometimes it gives the correct result of 6.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
' The function below converts a column reference (A - IV) to a column number between 1 and 256:
Public Function ColRef2ColNo(ColRef As String) As Integer
    ColRef2ColNo = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ColRef2ColNo = Range(ColRef & "1").Column
End Function
```

Comment: Access VBA has no idea what Range refers to (that is something belonging to Excel VBA) Do you have a reference to an Excel Application object somewhere in your code? PS you hardly ever need to do this type of conversion when working with Excel - the Cells() method for example can take either two numeric arguments (row/Column) or one numeric and one String argument - eg. Cells(5, "G")

Comment: I passed the worksheet object to the function and now it is working consistently.  **Thanks** for the suggestion.  I am using a numeric column because I am doing math in calculating the number of records that I am loading into a table, e.g. number of columns times number of rows equals number of rows that will be added to the table.

Comment: If you want to get the last used column in an Excel worksheet, you could use `lngMaxCol = objXLSheet.Cells(1, objXLSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`
`